# Ignore :hover in a specific class

Tags: css

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/8cTRL/

How do I make objects with the b class not change yellow when I hover? I know I can write

```
.a:hover.b { background-color:green }
```

but I'm trying not to repeat myself. The css is

```
.a:hover {
    background-color:yellow
}
.b {
    background-color:green
}
```

Comment: `.b:hover {
    background-color:green
}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can try this:

```
.a:hover {
    background-color:yellow
}

.a.b {
    background-color:green
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this add the  `b:hover` state on your initial `.b` selector:

```
.b, .b:hover {
  background-color:green
}
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cTRL/2/)**